Incrementing number in a row each time I print
I need to increment a value by 1 in K1 each time I print sheet number 1, 2, etc.
I used to have code that was saved and was working fine, but I lost it when I formatted the PC.
It used to ask me the number of pages needed to print and from which number to start.
When I use the below code, it works fine; but every time I print, the count starts from 1. I need to be able to print from whichever number I intend to.
Sub IncrementPrint()
'updateby Extendoffice
    Dim xCount As Variant
    Dim xScreen As Boolean
    Dim I As Long
    On Error Resume Next
LInput:
    xCount = Application.InputBox("Please enter the number of copies you want to print:", "Kutools for Excel")
    If TypeName(xCount) = "Boolean" Then Exit Sub
    If (xCount = "") Or (Not IsNumeric(xCount)) Or (xCount < 1) Then
        MsgBox "error entered, please enter again", vbInformation, "Kutools for Excel"
        GoTo LInput
    Else
        xScreen = Application.ScreenUpdating
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        For I = 1 To xCount
            ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value = " Company-00" & I
            ActiveSheet.PrintOut
        Next
        ActiveSheet.Range("A1").ClearContents
        Application.ScreenUpdating = xScreen
    End If
End Sub


Changing the I value to anything other than 1 will run the script, but not print any page.
Source file attached below
https://easyupload.io/mx7c4l
Thank you LP Chip.
Struggling for a while with code errors. Can you please add the corresponding lines or share the code on a link?
Sub IncrementPrint()
'updateby Extendoffice
    Dim xCount As Variant
    Dim xScreen As Boolean
    Dim I As Long
    On Error Resume Next
LInput:
    xCount = Application.InputBox("Please enter the number of copies you want to print:", "Kutools for Excel")
    If TypeName(xCount) = "Boolean" Then Exit Sub
    If (xCount = "") Or (Not IsNumeric(xCount)) Or (xCount < 1) Then
        MsgBox "error entered, please enter again", vbInformation, "Kutools for Excel"
        GoTo LInput
    Else
        xScreen = Application.ScreenUpdating
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        For I = 1 To xCount
            ActiveSheet.Range("K2").Value = " Sheet No:" & I
            ActiveSheet.PrintOut
        Next
        ActiveSheet.Range("K2").ClearContents
        Application.ScreenUpdating = xScreen
    For I = 0 + CountStart to xCount + CountStart - 1
    End If
End Sub



Doesn't this rule apply here (even if there is an external source)?

Peter,
Noted, jpeg removed and code updated.

The reason your script fails, is because you create a for loop that ran out of bounds. By adjusting 1 to a higher number than xCount is, you basically say: loop from 5 to 2 for example. In VBA, if the left value is bigger than the right, and you don't add a step -1, it will just skip the for loop. So the xCount value has to be increased also by the same amount.
To do this, you can make the following modification:
Add a new variable in your script: Something like CountStart, and either ask the user at script start, or fill it in manually.
Eg:
Dim CountStart as Integer = 1

Now adjust the for loop to keep the CountStart in mind.
For I = 0 + CountStart to xCount + CountStart - 1

